# How do I reduce number of abs functions

Tags: c++

I tried to make a function of getting  the "greatest common divider".

My aim was to cancel fractions(it looks like a/b, so if it's 3/6 it will become 1/3).

To do that I need "gcd" also for negative numbers, BUT "gcd" doesn't work like this, so u have to use abs function.

```cpp
int NOD(int a,int b){
    if(abs(a)==abs(b)){
        return abs(a);
    }
    if(abs(a)<abs(b)){
        return NOD(abs(a),abs(b-a));
    }
    else{
        return NOD(abs(a-b),abs(b));
    }
}
```

How do I reduce the number of these abs functions???

Comment: `return gcd(abs(a), abs(b))`. Also there's a better implementation of gcd involving modulo division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters:

```
int NOD(int a, int b) {
    int abs_a = abs(a);
    int abs_b = abs(b);
    if (abs_a == abs_b)
        return abs_a;
    if (abs_a < abs_b)
        return NOD(abs_a, abs(b-a));
    return NOD(abs(a-b), abs_b);
}
```

And to be honest, I'm pretty sure that you don't even need the `abs(b-a)` or `abs(a-b)`, because they will be "abs-ed" in the next function call, right?

So you can simply go along with:

```
int NOD(int a, int b) {
    int abs_a = abs(a);
    int abs_b = abs(b);
    if (abs_a == abs_b)
        return abs_a;
    if (abs_a < abs_b)
        return NOD(abs_a, b-a);
    return NOD(a-b, abs_b);
}
```

And if you want to get rid of `abs` altogether, then you an simply mimic its behavior in your code:

```
int NOD(int a, int b) {
    int abs_a = a > 0 ? a : -a;
    int abs_b = b > 0 ? b : -b;
    if (abs_a == abs_b)
        return abs_a;
    if (abs_a < abs_b)
        return NOD(abs_a, b-a);
    return NOD(a-b, abs_b);
}
```